# Google Charts with client side data population

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I've been looking at possibilities to populate a chart from Google Charts with live client data. I have tried solutions which send requests to the back-end but I would like to keep this side separate from the client environment and the API is currently still undergoing development.

This is the example code for a standard pie chart

```
//JS Code
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width':400,
            'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
//HTML Code
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Is there a way to populate Google Charts by retrieving data from a table that is being displayed with jQuery or even pure JavaScript? I imagine it would look something like this:

```
data.addRows([
            [$('#textfield1').getAttribute('value'), 3],
            [$('#textfield2').getAttribute('value'), 1],
            [$('#textfield3').getAttribute('value'), 1],
            [$('#textfield4').getAttribute('value'), 1],
            [$('#textfield5').getAttribute('value'), 2]
        ]);
```

Does anyone have experience attempting this or even know if it is a possibility?

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure javascript, let us suppose you have the above hardcoded `DataTable` `rows` in a HTML `<table>` :

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>topping</th>
            <th>slices</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Mushrooms</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Onions</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Olives</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zucchini</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pepperoni</td><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can read that table and use it as a source for the charts `DataTable` this way :

```js
...
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr');
for (var i=0;i<tableRows.length;i++) {
    data.addRow([ 
       tableRows[i].cells[0].textContent,
       parseInt(tableRows[i].cells[1].textContent)
    ]);
}
...
```

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/akLf3gL9/**

Notice `parseInt(...)` it is important that the data we inject on the #2th column actually is typeof number, otherwise visualization will fail.